# Congratulations Ed Beal on reaching 100k rep!

Tags: discussion

It's a substantial accomplishment (especially for someone who's not an electrician), and I greatly appreciate [Ed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/44366/ed-beal)'s depth of experience and willingness to share time here.

Well done, Ed.

Comment: FYI he's not around any more. Last seen "more than a month ago", last posted in May 2023, posted only twice in all of 2023, last post before that was August 2022.

Comment: There's not a lot of users at that rep level anymore. Community congrats should still be appropriate as long as the achievement is uncommon

Comment: @nobody Ed's name still shows up plenty of places - e.g., old questions that come up because of "Community" or because someone tried to answer a question with another question. He is one of those people I recognize from when I started posting here and definitely admire & respect.

Answer (score 16):

Yes! Congratulations Ed!

Thank you for sharing your knowledge and expertise.  I always enjoy learning from you.

I was going through some of my favourite content you have authored, and it reminded me how much I've learned from you.  Thank you for your generosity.

Answer (score 3):

Best wishes Ed Beal wherever you are — thanks to you and other frequent posters here from whom I've learned a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations Ed.  Hope you're doing well. Miss seeing you here. You shared  lot of your knowledge with us and I thank you for that.